# ClassNotFoundException thrown at SpringBoot runtime

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, runtimeexception

I packaged the classes of other modules into BOOT-INF/classes directory, SpringBoot can start normally, but when running to the cache serialization of an object will throw a ClassNotFoundException, what is the reason? Is it related to the class loader?

Here is my Maven configuration:

```
   <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <includes>
                <include>
                    <groupId>nothing</groupId>
                    <artifactId>nothing</artifactId>
                </include>
            </includes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <classpathPrefix>commonLibs/</classpathPrefix>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>unpack-dependence</id>
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>unpack</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <artifactItems>
                        <artifactItem>
                            <groupId>xxx</groupId>
                            <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                            <type>jar</type>
                            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                            <outputDirectory>./target/classes</outputDirectory>
                            <includes>**/*.class</includes>
                        </artifactItem>
                    </artifactItems>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-dependence</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>./target/commonLibs</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Why are you doing all those things in the first place? Why not use a simple `spring-boot-maven-plugin` instead of packaging a custom jar and unpacking stuff? Feels like you are overcomplicating things.

Comment: As M. Deinum already mentioned use the spring-boot-maven-plugin and remove maven-jar-plugin as well as maven-dependency-plugin...

Comment: Also why: `I packaged the classes of other modules into BOOT-INF/classe` that is wrong. Let spring-boot-maven-plugin do it's work...

Comment: I need to strip out the third-party dependencies into a common directory to avoid having to re-upload them every time I update; as for the unpacking configuration, it's because the non-third-party dependencies may modify it and need to be updated every time I package it.